Ошибка при чтении модуля из скрипта Python в VSCode
Не так давно изучаю python, использую VSCode и на первом же шаге столкнулся с проблемой:

Открываю VSCode -> Open folder... (Создаю папку в директории диска D:\..);
Отрываю терминал, создаю виртуальное окружение:

python -m venv venv


Активирую виртуальное окружение:

venv\Scripts\activate


Устанавливаю в виртуальном окружении необходимый модуль, допустим requests:

(venv) pip install requests

Установка проходит успешно.

Создаю файл main.py, делаю импорт модуля, запускаю код:

import requests


Получаю ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "d:\PythonProject\CoinBot\main.py", line 1, in <module> import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'


Поиск решение в гугл натолкнул на мысль, что проблема либо в импорте модуля, либо в интерпретаторе, либо нужно настроить VSCode. Если кто-то сможет помочь развернутым ответом или статьей для понимания сути проблемы буду признателен.
P.S.:

Предупреждение PowerShell выглядит так:


Код запускал через команду Run:




А как запускается код, так же из (venv) your/path python main.py

upd: И еще не плохо бы разобраться что там за предупреждение powershell <!>, и запустить не файл с import ..., а пустой файл с одной строкой print(123), а потом уже разбираться с импортами.

Файл запускал через кнопку Run в правой верхней части. Код print('123') запускается без проблем. Предупреждение PowerShell сейчас подгружу.

ну так а почему же ты не попробовал его перезапустить(расширение а не скрипт), там же написано что не совсем корректно работает расширение python, и даже слева на значке расширений горит (1). Такое впечатление, что расширение не смогло добавить venv в среду powershell. Перезапусти потом опять пробуй

upd: среда которую ты видишь (venv) это одно, а то что запустит расширение кнопкой Run это уже другой терминал откроется

Надо установить интерпретатор для vscode

@AlexanderLonberg перезапустил Code Runner и все заработало, спасибо! Если не сложно объясните из-за чего это возникает? Если я правильно понял, то при создании проекта расширение Code Runner подключается к глобальному интерпретатору. При создании виртуального окружения я меняю путь к интерпретатору, но Code Runner запускает его из другой папки, а не из окружения, верно? Получается каждый раз мне придется перезапускать расширение?

@Макс Зачем тебе "Code Runner". Все чем я пользуюсь TypeScript/Python/C# запускается встроенными  в соответствующие расширения лаунчерами. Я эту ошибку PowerShell впервые вижу - "Code Runner" не дал нормально запустится расширению "Python", да еще и настройки требует. Дополнительные настройки запуска/перезапуска обеспечиваются файлом .vscode/launch.json, а не вредными расширениями.

Подтверждаю, Code runner для запуска кода на Python не нужен, достаточно стандартного расширения для Python. Code runner не умеет нормально работать с виртуальными окружениями.

import telebot

token = '8142128318:AAHTpQ5wq4SWjOIWJtriffQso2EvECKJF4M'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(messang):
    user_id = messang.chat.id
    bot.send_messange(user_id ,'привет :)' )

bot.polling()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Не понятно, как данный фрагмент кода отвечает на вопрос ТС?
